# Is it possible to to create an environment dependent controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to have a controller for a web-api that is only usable in a specific environment, e.g. Development.

Is this possible, and if so how would I do it?

Comment: why do you want a dev only controller? why not create a dev only environment?

Comment: Welcome! Please add more clarification to your answer and add more context.

Comment: @Sean I mean to use a development environment, but I'm not sure on how to have a controller that only works in a specific environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your controller with `#if debug` statement:

```
#if DEBUG
<your controller code>
#endif
```

This way you will be able to access the controller only on debug builds.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why you want a dev only controller, but similar to @shoter I would also use the #if but instead wrap the route.

```
#if DEBUG
  routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
  );
#endif
```

This way the route does not get created on production builds.